# Maintaining time dimension (Z) for an aggregated Raster

Tags: r, datetime, aggregate, raster, netcdf

I'm aggregating a large RasterBrick by lat, lon, and layer. My original RasterBrick object has a set Z dimension (i.e. there are dates assigned to each layer), but I lose these dates when I aggregate the Raster. Instead, the Z dimension returns to layer.1, layer.2, etc. rather than a Date dimension.

I need a list of the dates associated with my aggregated Raster (so I can eventually use the rts package to make a time series) but am unsure which dates are associated with which layers after I aggregate.

**How can I ensure I'm getting an accurate list of dates corresponding to layers post-aggregation?**

I started with a large dataset of modeled sea surface temperature data. I extracted the data from a netCDF file.

```
rbrick <- brick(netCDF.data, xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs="WGS84", transpose=T) %>% flip(2) # Create a RasterBrick from my netCDF data. lon and lat values are also extracted from the netCDF

yr <- ncvar_get(gfdl,'year'); mth <- ncvar_get(gfdl,'month'); day <- ncvar_get(gfdl,'day') # Extract time variables from the netCDF
tim <- as.POSIXct(paste(yr,mth,day,sep='-'),tz='UTC') # Format dates
rbrick.t <- setZ(rbrick, tim, name="Date") # Add Z dimension to RasterBrick
rbrick.t # Check the RasterBrick data--there's a beautiful Date dimension at the bottom!

weekly.5 <- aggregate(rbrick.t, fact=c(5, 6, 7), expand=T) # Lower the resolution of the RasterBrick to weekly data times a .5 degree grid cell resolution

weekly.5 # Check the RasterBrick data--my Date dimension is gone :(
```

Eventually, I would like to be able to get a time series of dates from my aggregated RasterBrick so I can make a time series out of the data using the rts package like so:

```
rt <- rts(rbrick, tim) # Make a rts object with time associated from a list of Dates
plot(rt[15]) # Plot the time series for cell number 15
```

If I can't keep my Z dimension when I aggregate the Raster, **how can I make an accurate list of dates for the aggregated Raster** to input into rts?

Comment: I realize that I can use "agg.tim <- tim[seq(1, length(tim), 7)]" to make an aggregated time series... but how do I check that this is correct to how my RasterBrick is actually aggregating?

Comment: Adding some data would likely help pursuit of this, perhaps link or? Expect that some responses will be in terra rather than raster. actually terra as the `rts`vignette uses `terra`.

Comment: you should look at [tapp](https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/tapp.html) in the `terra` package, in particular at the `index` argument

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help. However, the `terra::tapp` function preserves in some way the time information when the `index` argument is set to a time frame (like "week" in your case). See the example below

```
  library(terra)
    #create a daily sequence for 1 year
    namer <- seq(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2021-12-31"), by="day")
    #create example data with 1 layer for each day
    values <- rnorm(length(namer)*100)
    r <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals =values ,nlyrs=length(namer),time=namer)
    #aggregation
    weekly <- tapp(r,"week",fun=mean)
    agg <- aggregate(weekly,fact=c(5,6),fun=mean)
    
    #eventually assign as time for each layer the first day of the week
    time(agg) <- namer[seq(1,length(namer),7)]
```

The layers' names are listed as `week_1, week_2, ...`, while the time slot of the raster is filled with the first day of the week used for the aggregation.
Two things here:

1. You did not specify any function for the layer aggregation. Here, I suppose you wanted the average values over each week;
2. When aggregating over time, the time information is lost. You will have a new raster with another time information not directly related to the previous one (e.g., while 2023/01/01 is meaningful for you, week_53 could not be. You can assign one arbitrary day of the week_53 to its time slot).
3. If you want to create a list of each day used for the aggregation of each new layer, you could use the information in the Details section of `?tapp`

> "week" follows the ISO 8601 definition. Weeks start on Monday. If the week containing 1 January has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered week "01". Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year (week "52" or "53", and the next week is week 1.

So the list would be like this:

```
library(lubridate)    
list_days <- split(time(r),isoweek(time(r)))
```

Note that  `isoweek(time(r))` returns the weekly index for each day.
To confirm that `tapp` has used the same identical index, you can try:

```
isoweekly <- tapp(r,index=isoweek(time(r)),fun=mean)
```

And you will see that it is identical to the raster named `weekly` (except for the layer name obviously